# How to change the user name of certification?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I have created hyperledger fabric network.

I would like to change the default user certifacation name such as User1@domain and User2@domain when issuing multiple user certificates using cryptogen.

Is there any way to customize the certification name?

Comment: Not at the moment, but would you want a custom patch that you can compile and use?

Comment: I don't need a custom patch right now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the manual of Hyperledger Fabric, when you create your Network, you use the **[cryptogen](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html#crypto-generator)** tool to generate the cryptographic material (x509 certs) for your various network entities. These certificates are representative of identities.

Cryptogen consumes a file `crypto-config.yaml` that contains the network topology and allows us to generate a set of certificates and keys for both the Organizations and the components that belong to those Organizations. So, you have to configure that file to customize the certification name.

Comment: So how to config crypto-config.yaml file?